# PHP invalid character error

Tags: php, xml, dom

I'm getting this error when running this code:
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Invalid Character Error' in test.php:29 Stack trace: #0 test.php(29): DOMDocument->createElement('1OhmStable', 'a') #1 {main} thrown in test.php on line 29`

The nodes that from the original XML file do contain invalid characters, but as I am stripping the invalid characters away from the nodes, the nodes should be created. What type of encoding do I need to do on the original XML document? Do I need to decode the saveXML?

```
function __cleanData($c) 
{
    return preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", "",$c);
}
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->load('test.xml');    
$xml->formatOutput = true; 

$append = array();
foreach ($xml->getElementsByTagName('product') as $product ) 
    {
        foreach($product->getElementsByTagName('name') as $name ) 
        {

            $append[] = $name;
        }
                foreach ($append as $a)  
                {
                    $nodeName = __cleanData($a->textContent);

                        $element = $xml->createElement(htmlentities($nodeName) , 'a');
                }
        $product->removeChild($xml->getElementsByTagName('details')->item(0));
        $product->appendChild($element);
    }

$result = $xml->saveXML();
$file = "data.xml";
file_put_contents($file,$result);
```

This is what the original XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="/v1/xsl/xml_pretty_printer.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<products>
<product>
<modelNumber>M100</modelNumber>
<itemId>1553725</itemId>
<details>
  <detail>
    <name>1 Ohm Stable</name>
    <value>600 x 1</value>
  </detail>
 </details>
</product>
 </products>
```

The new document is supposed to look like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="/v1/xsl/xml_pretty_printer.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<products>
<product>
<modelNumber>M100</modelNumber>
<itemId>1553725</itemId>
  <1 Ohm Stable>

  </1 Ohm Stable>

  </product>
 </products>
```

Comment: you are like talking to yourself, where is the XML?

Comment: Why you post the clean version?

Comment: The xml you posted is after you removed the invalid characters? Why not you post the original version ?

Comment: No that is the original version. I will post what the output is supposed to look like.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5888/discussion-between-rpm-and-ajreal)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply you can not use an element name start with number

```
1OhmStable  <-- rename this
_1OhmStable <-- this is fine
```

[php parse xml - error: StartTag: invalid element name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588888/php-parse-xml-error-starttag-invalid-element-name)

A nice article :- http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/07/25/namingparts.html

> A Name is a token beginning with a letter or one of a few punctuation characters, and continuing with letters, digits, hyphens, underscores, colons, or full stops, together known as name characters.

Answer (score 6):

You have not written where you get that error. In case it's after you cleaned the value, this is my guess:

```
preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", "",$c);
```

This replacement is not written for UTF-8 encoded strings (which are used by DOMDocument). You can make it UTF-8 compatible by using the [`u`-modifier (PCRE8)<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

```
preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/u", "",$c);
                            ^
```

It's just a guess, I suggest you make it more precise in your question which part of your code triggers the error.

Answer (score 1):

Even if `__cleandata()` will remove all other characters than latin alphabets a-z and numbers, it doesn't necessarily guarantee that the result is a valid XML name. Your function can return strings that begin with a number but numbers are illegal name **start** characters in XML, they can only appear in a name after the first name character. Also spaces are forbidden in names, so that is another point where your expected XML output would fail.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure scripts have same encoding: if it's UTF make sure they are without Byte Order Mark (BOM) at very begin of file.
To do that open your XML file with a text editor like Notepad++ and convert your file in "UTF-8 without BOM".

I had a similar error, but with a [json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635682/error-retrieving-json-with-php)